# Efficient, fast way to Benchmark in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, benchmarking

I am working on a project  with **CodeIgniter 3** and I want to check the time of certain section of my code for performance analysis. I tried using the ([benchmark](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/benchmark.html)) class found in the documentation.
[image: Benchmark library CI3]

Can anyone suggest how to do it or where to find this class library to add it to my project
and Thanks.

Comment: *This class is initialized automatically by the system so there is no need to do it manually.* Try to re-install the latest [CI 3.x version (3.1.13)](https://codeigniter.com/download)

Comment: Can you share the relevant code snippet?